# Preventing __doPostBack going to the server before the whole page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is there a way to make __doPostBack wait for the page to be loaded before it goes to the server?

Sometimes our users click controls at the top of the page before the page is fully loaded/rendered, which results in an incomplete form being sent to the server.

I am wondering if there is something I can do with Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager (add an event handler?, configure it?) that would check if the page is loaded and if it is not it would wait for it?

This is an ASP.NET 3.5 app.

Note: A possible solution is make the controls call some "__doPostBack_WhenLoaded" method that would do the check and add the __doPostBack call to the onLoad event if needed. I think thought there would be a better way :).

Comment: The simplest way of doing this is activating page controls through javascript code after page load using onload event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to do what I wanted by extending the PageRequestManager, so here comes a quick and dirty solution I ended up with. I created my own __doPostBack function, which does the checking and then call the actual function directly or adds it to the queue to be processed on load:

```
    var WebPageFullyLoaded = false;

    $(function() {
        WebPageFullyLoaded = true;
    });
    var oldDoPostBack = __doPostBack;
    __doPostBack = function (eventTarget, eventArgument) {
        if (!WebPageFullyLoaded) {
            $(function () {
                oldDoPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument);
            });
        }
        else {
            oldDoPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery?  If so, you could enable the page controls once the document is ready (finished loading).  [jsfiddle.net/qtg94](http://jsfiddle.net/qtg94/)

Page Control

```
<input type="submit" name="name" id="controlID" disabled="true">
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#controlID').prop('disabled', false);
});
```